# R: Add data from row to a column with conditions

Tags: r

I've got two data frames,

```
df1

number    x_1    y_1
1         a      a
2         a      b
3         b      b 
4         c      b
5         c      c

df2

number_1  x_1  y_1  number_2  x_2  y_2
1                   2
1                   3
1                   4
1                   5
2                   3
2                   4
2                   5
3                   4
3                   5
4                   5
```

I want to add data into the columns x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2 based on whether number_1 and number_2 match the numbers in the number column in df1. So in the first two rows of df2, I should have:

```
df2

number_1  x_1  y_1  number_2  x_2  y_2
1         a    a    2         a    b 
1         a    a    3         b    b
```

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work and it takes extremely long with an extremely huge dataset:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1))
  for(j in 1:nrow(df2))
    if(df2$number_1[j] == df1$number[i])
      df2$x_1[j] = df1$x_1[i]
      df2$y_1[j] = df1$y_1[i]
    if(df2$number_2[j] == df1$number_1[i])
      df2$x_1[j] = df1$x_1[i]
      df2$y_1[j] = df$y_1[i]
```

I'm a beginner so I'll really appreciate if you could explain the steps you propose too. Thank you very much.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. From what I understand, you are taking df2's x_1 and y_1, and adding columns 2:3 of df1 IF there is a match between df2$number_1 and df1$number. Then you do this again for number_2.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I think your answer is the one that OP wants here. Please consider to post the comment as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either `merge` or `left_join` from `dplyr`

```
merge(df1,
     merge(df1,df2[,c(1,4)], by.x='number', by.y='number_1'),
        by.x='number', by.y='number_2')
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(
    left_join(df2[c(1,4)], df1, by=c('number_1'='number')) ,
        df1, by=c('number_2'='number'))
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned in the comments, `match` can be used here.

```
df2[c("x_1", "y_1")] <- df1[match(df2$number_1, df1$number), 2:3]
df2[c("x_2", "y_2")] <- df1[match(df2$number_2, df1$number), 2:3]
```